# How to get the center of specific cluster in sklearn.cluster.MeanShift

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mean-shift

I have a trained MeanShift object (`ms`). It has a simple list of centers. How to determine the label that a center belongs to?
I am aware about `labels_`, but I do not see a connection between `labels_` and `cluster_centers_`.

```
print(ms.cluster_centers_)

[[  40.7177164   -73.99183542]
 [  33.44943805 -112.00213969]
 [  33.44638027 -111.90188756]
 ..., 
 [  46.7323875  -117.0001651 ]
 [  29.6899563   -95.8996757 ]
 [  31.3787916   -95.3213317 ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of `labels` is the dimension of your original dataset. It gives the index of the corresponding cluster. So the associated cluster center for an entry `i` in the original data is `cluster_centers_[labels_[i]]`.

You can see in the example from sklearn that they are looping on the number of unique labels, and using `labels == k` to select all the data with that label (`X[labels_ == k]`):
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-mean-shift-py

Comment: Do you mean a label (which is an integer number) is the index of a center?

Comment: Indeed, let me change my answer.

Comment: Checked vocabuary. I think correct word is power or cardinaity, not dimension.

Comment: Actually, the dimension of the array, so its shape ;)